# Allow space in textbox only if any existing characters or number in that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox in which I need validation in such way that it should not allow spaces if textbox is empty. If any values are there in textbox then only it should allow spaces. I am trying below code but not working

```
var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

$("#input1").on("blur ", function() {
  function alphanumeric(username) { 
    if (username.value.match(letters)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $('#input1').on('keypress', function(e) {
       if (e.which == 32)
         return false;
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't add event handlers within event handlers.  Everytime you `blur` you get another `keypress` - just add `keypress` by itself and check the content there.

Comment: Is you remove the `$` symbol in your regex, I think it will work the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#input1').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "")
      if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
  });
});
```

**[Online Demo (jsFiddle)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/zt2g80yw/4/)**

Answer (score 3):

if you are using form, you do not need any javascript

---

```html
<form action='/'>
  <input pattern="\s*\S+.*" title="space only is not allowed" required/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just trim?

```
username.trim()
```

after that you can just return the result of match.

Comment: As SUN mentioned, he want to disable entering space if input is empty, but `.trim` removes spaces from `username`.

Comment: So when there are only spaces the function will return false and the form validation will fail? Is that not the desired result?
return username.value.trim().match(letters); 
Where letters should also include the option to include spaces.

Comment: `if (e.which == 32) return false` in this case is for entering characters not validation. Validation method should be different method to check username.

Comment: As SUN mentioned in title of question, he tried to allow entering space in `textbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex seems wrong.
You're not allowing spaces characters.

Try this one instead: `/\S/`

`\S`  is any non whitespace character.

If you want to start by a character, it will become `/^\S/`.

`^` is when you want to start by the following character
`$` is when you want to finish by the previous character

Answer (score 1):

Add a function on your `blur` event that will trim the values which will remove preceding and succeeding whitespace. If the value is empty it will result in `''` .

```js
$("#input1").on("blur", function () { 
  if($(this).val().trim() === ''){
    alert('empty value');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input1' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function allowSpace(event) {
    var textboxValue = document.getElementById("myTextbox").value;

    if (textboxValue.length > 0) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```